# The proper location for #define statements in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios

What is the proper place to put `#define` statements in Objective-C?

They technically work in a number of locations, but what is the "right" place to put them?

Between the `#include` statements and the `@interface` statement in my .h file??

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define BAR        1
#define FOO        2

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
```

Or perhaps inside the `@interface` statement?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

#define BAR        1
#define FOO        2
```

Is there a best practice I should be following?

Comment: You chose the right place. If you like you can but them at the end of the file. The complete file gets included.

Comment: I don't understand this need to know the best way of doing anything, even if all the ways you know are working.If works it's fine.

Comment: See my comment below to Binyamin Sharet.  Doxygen doesn't seem to like the #define statements appearing before the comments for the interface.  That's what prompted me to ask about the "correct" place to put #define statements.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I think it is a good question. Unless you will always write code alone, it is good to learn and understand common best practices. It makes your code easier to read and maintain by other developers.

Comment: Ok @RamyAlZuhouri I use goto: statements which work instead of functions. It works, so it's fine right? Wrong... if you have taken any sort of computer science course you will know why there are best practices that should be followed.

Comment: Good practices are useful when there is a real reason for using them. "goto statement is harmful": that's why goto is considered a bad practice.But without a reason there isn't a good and bad practice. I've seen people even asking if it's better to call accessors like [obj ivar] or obj.ivar .Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When used in a .h file like this, I treat them like they are global variables. Therefore I put them after the import statements and before the interface. In other words, like your first option.

Comment: Since there doesn't seem to be an overall consensus, I'll count your response as the "correct" answer.  Besides, you agree with me so you must be right!  ;)